# Manage user access in SharePoint hosted add-in

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-permissions

I'm developing SharePoint hosted add-ins and I need a way to manage user access to the apps I'm developing. For example, I have a site with 3 different SharePoint add-ins that access to lists in the same site, I would like to let a group of users to access 1 application and don't access to the others applications installed.

I came up with 2 different ideas to reach this:

1. Create SharePoint groups that corresponds to each application, add the users I want to have access and then in the SharePoint add-in get all the users from a certain group and check if the current user belongs to that group.
2. Create a subsite for each SharePoint add-in and manage the permissions from "Site permissions" under "Site settings"

Also I would like to know as well if there is a way to manage "roles" inside the application, for example let some users with permissions as "read-only", other group of users with "edit" and other one with "delete".

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing and I was able to get what I needed by access to the user permissions page inside the SharePoint add in:

> /_layouts/15/user.aspx

Then click on "Stop Inheriting permissions", delete all groups grant permissions by adding users or SharePoint groups with it corresponding permissions level.

In my case I created a SharePoint group with no permissions at site level, added that SharePoint group to the SharePoint add-in user page  with "View" permissions, so the users in that group were able to only access the application, but cannot access to the lists or contents in site level, if we wanted to access additional content in the site, then we need to add the permission at the site level (in my case I added "Read") and the users were able to read all the contents from the lists. Of course with the read permissions the users will be able to access the others SharePoint add-in so it is important to stop inheriting permissions for all of the sharepoint add-ins in order to isolate them.